# how I can turn off computer on lan?

Tags: wireless

How I can turn off computer on LAN?

I shutdown a computer that is on LAN via Wi-Fi. I have his IP and MAC address that I do now?

Comment: IP- and mac-address are not sufficient to issue a shutdown. You need ssh access or something like ipmi to control the power.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this:

```
ssh user@LAN_ADDRESS 'shutdown -P 0'
```

Press enter and put the password of the user declared in the command above, then this LAN PC will be powered off.

As was said, this LAN PC need to have a SSH Server installed. You can do this by running on this PC the follow command:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```